# What constitutes a large WMI repository and what can cause it to grow?

Tags: windows-7, wmi, repository, login

Our organization is experiencing lengthy startup times after improper shutdowns that seem to be tied to the size of the WMI repository.  For example, a repository folder size of 50 megs might result in 10 minutes added to startup time, while 500 megs might take a whole hour.

There's [a hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2505348) for this sort of problem, but I'd like to track down what's causing the repository to grow.  Certain pieces of software?  Multiple user profiles?  In some cases, a couple hundred different users might have profiles on a given machine.  We do not use roaming profiles, and we use [delprof2](http://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/) to clear these profiles out periodically, but it doesn't have any effect on this repository size.

Comment: Having the same issue and don't know why the WMI is getting so large. I've seen it as small as 100MB and as large as 900MB. If I searched every computer in our system, I'm sure I could find one over 1GB. The strange issue is that it won't necessarily effect all user accounts all the time. However we've seen it will even effect the local Admin account log-in time. We also are using the Delprof2 to clear out accounts, but will just move to local GP for deleting accounts over certain days old. As of right now we're applying hot fix KB2617858 & KB2709630, & those seem to be resolving the slow log-

Comment: Good to know we're not the only ones. :)  We've had decent success with KB2617858 and are moving toward applying this all over, but it's more of a band aid than a fix.  It turns a 30-60 minute startup process into 4 or 5 minutes pretty reliably, but "normal" should be something under 2 minutes, ideally.